# FKs on all tables for status column

Tags: database, schema

I have a column: "Status" in every table in my DB. The purpose of it is to show if the given row is in use or if it has been deactivated. So values can be (0=deactive and 1=active). Two ways I see this: I can have enums or I am thinking if it is better to keep this column as a FK which references the main system data dictionary table which has all the codes used on the system. (website)

The benefit is every table, every row can then be centralized through this FK. So if I ever want to check all rows which are deactive on my system I can from this table as all the child tables will have like status = ID 233, where 233 = deactive in the data dictionary table.

Any benefit or should I stick with the old way of enums?. Also I am thinking if I need one more status for deleted or is that same as deactivated?

Comment: Just a language note, the opposite of "active" is "inactive". There is no such word "deactive", although the verb "deactivate" is perfectly OK. I usually don't fix people's grammar, but as you're going to use these terms a lot, I thought you might find this useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only ever going to have two states (active/inactive) then there is no need for a foriegn key to a separate status table. you can just use a bit column if your database supports this.

If you are going to have more states, then yes it *may* be a good idea to have a separate status table, but it isn't really *necessary* unless you want to write queries that are friendly and easy to read (`where status = 'inactive'` is a lot easier to understand than `where status = 0`), or you intend to change what a value means (in which case you just change the description in the `status` table).

As for introducing the new value of `deleted` - personally i would consider having that as a separate column, as it has a different meaning to actice or inactive, and you may not want to overwrite the state of your row when it becomes deleted (for example, you retain the information that a column was active or inactive when it was deleted).

Comment: Hm, for this question it works. I'll ask another question on the different statuses i need then because an account can have so many statuses.